# barcodeReader.Decode(writeableBitMap) returning null

Tags: winrt-xaml, zxing

When I try a barcode that I've told is a CASE39 barcode I always get null returned from the decode

```
  if (cbBarcode.IsChecked == true)
            {
                var photoStorageFile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("scan.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

                Size aspectRatio = new Size(3, 1);
                dialog.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = aspectRatio;
                StorageFile file = await dialog.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
                string ImageValues = "bbc_photo" + x;
                var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
                // initialize with 1,1 to get the current size of the image
                var writeableBmp = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
                writeableBmp.SetSource(stream);
                // and create it again because otherwise the WB isn't fully initialized and decoding
                // results in a IndexOutOfRange
                writeableBmp = new WriteableBitmap(writeableBmp.PixelWidth, writeableBmp.PixelHeight);
                stream.Seek(0);
                writeableBmp.SetSource(stream);
                var result = ScanBitMap(writeableBmp);
                if (result != null)
                {
                    MessageDialog dialog2 = new MessageDialog(result.Text.ToString());
                    await dialog2.ShowAsync();
                    //photoStorageFile = writeableBmp;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageDialog errdialog = new MessageDialog("Error reading barcode.. Please try again");
                    await errdialog.ShowAsync();
                }
                return;



     private Result ScanBitMap(WriteableBitmap writeableBmp)
     {
         var barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader
         {
             AutoRotate = true,
             Options = new DecodingOptions
             {
                 TryHarder = true,
                 // restrict to one or more supported types, if necessary
                 PossibleFormats = new []
                  {
                    BarcodeFormat.CODE_39
                   }
             }
         };
         var result = barcodeReader.Decode(writeableBmp);

         if (result != null)
         {
             CapturedPhoto.Source = writeableBmp;
         }

         return result;
     }
```

I recently added the code for Options but nothing seems to be changing the output coming from the Decode function. I am writing this for an app on the tablet that runs windows 8.1 metro app xaml.

Comment: Are you looking at the images it's creating to make sure that they're correct? Also, what's with the strange Uri you are trying to create? The method you are using to set the source of `writeableBmp` seems suspect. Have you tried `WriteableBitmapEx`'s load extensions?

Comment: The method employed to set the source of the writeableBmp was taken directly from zxing.net example https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: Unfortunately that link is to the main page and not the specific example, of which the example on the main codeplex page for the site is very different from the one you have implemented. Further, have you done the other checks to make sure the image is being processed before passing to ZXing properly?

Comment: We as a company have decided to drop this one, because decoding of images is very picky and by the time our managers have the image in focus and cropped properly they could've just typed in the number.

Comment: One question however, don't get me wrong by asking this Nate but what makes you an expert on Zxing barcode processing if you've never done it before, which I'm guessing you haven't by your responses???

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer to this question is to not use Zxing barcode scanner sdk and download the Easy Barcode Scanner Free windows app because it will decode barcodes and is easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in that way for EAN_13 so I think that for CODE_39 it should work too (Windows RT):

```
    private async Task<Result> ScanBitmap(WriteableBitmap writeableBmp)
    {
        var barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader
        {
            AutoRotate = true,
            Options =
            {
                TryHarder = true,
                PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> {BarcodeFormat.EAN_13}
            }
        };

        var pixels = await ConvertBitmapToByteArray(writeableBmp);

        var result = barcodeReader.Decode(new RGBLuminanceSource(pixels, writeableBmp.PixelWidth, writeableBmp.PixelHeight, RGBLuminanceSource.BitmapFormat.BGRA32));

        if (result != null)
        {
            CaptureImage.Source = writeableBmp;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private async Task<byte[]> ConvertBitmapToByteArray(WriteableBitmap bitmap)
    {
        var pixelStream = bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
        var pixels = new byte[pixelStream.Length];
        await pixelStream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
        return pixels;
    }
```