# I'm looking for a barcode scanner that will decode code 39 barcodes from the webcam on my tablet

Tags: winrt-xaml, zxing

I'm looking for a barcode scanner that will decode code 39 barcodes from the webcam on my tablet, tried zxing sdk and doesn't seem to work, the decode function is sending back a null pointer like it can't read code 39 barcodes.

Comment: If you could post your code that would be helpful. ZXing explicitly supports Code 39 according to the documentation. Make sure you're using the most up-to-date version. Make sure you're using either a `MultiFormatReader` or a `Code39Reader`.

Comment: code is found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488036/barcodereader-decodewriteablebitmap-returning-null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download the free windows store app called "Easy Barcode Scanner Free" from William Barrett Simms